# ptwrite intrinsic ordering guarantees

Tags: x86, trace, intrinsics

When using the Intel processor trace [ptwrite](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptwrite) logging instruction for tracing and possibly timestamping like this:

```
// compile with: -mptwrite

#include <x86gprintrin.h>

void foo()
{
    // ...
    _ptwrite64(a);
    // ...
    f();
    // ...
    _ptwrite64(b);
    // ...
}
```

What are the ordering guarantees gcc and clang provide for the _ptwrite64 intrnsic?

Does the ptwrite intrinsic (and/or the `__builtin_ia32_ptwrite64` builtin it wraps, as of gcc 13) acts as a compiler barrier?

Or does gcc (or clang) allows itself to simply reorder the `f()` function call before `_ptwrite64(a)` (or after `_ptwrite64(b)`)?

If ptwrite doesn't work as a compiler barrier, is switching to inline assembler (with the right annotations) the next best thing for creating a compiler barrier?

Otherwise, is there a way for a builtin/intrinsic to look up whether it acts as a compiler barrier?

Comment: I'd hope `_ptwrite64` has some ordering semantics but I have no idea, I haven't tried it.  re: compiler barriers, `asm("" ::: "memory")` in GNU C is the normal compiler memory barrier.  It's implicitly `volatile`, and the memory clobber makes the compiler assume that any globally-reachable memory might have been read and written, like a non-inline function call.  `std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)` should also work in practice with zero asm instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes The `unspec_volatile` qualifier in the [definition of pwrite in i386.md](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/9693459e030977d6e906ea7eb587ed09ee4fddbd/gcc/config/i386/i386.md#L26238) possibly has the same effect as  `asm("" ::: "memory") `, however, I couldn't find good documentation on that qualifier. FWIW, other builtins such as rdtsc and rdtscp are also defined with `unspec_volatile`. For clang I couldn't find a similar definition ([see also](https://reviews.llvm.org/D46540).

Comment: That just makes it like `asm volatile` instead of plain `asm`, so `int start = __rdtsc()` and `int stop = __rdtsc() - start;` can't do common subexpression elimination and use the return value twice for two calls with the same inputs.  (An `asm` statement with at least one output is not volatile by default, and is treated as a pure function of its inputs unless otherwise specified, even if the number of inputs is 0.  Fun fact: the `rdpmc` builtin had a bug for a while where it wasn't `volatile` so the compiler could assume two calls produced the same value.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/T1x91WTjv shows that `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` is not a memory barrier; GCC does dead-store elimination across it.  Same for `_ptwrite64()`.  So if your `f()` inlined, it's certainly possible some of the work could move outside.